# How can I simulate having no GPS location or poor location

Tags: android, android-emulator, location

I'm struggling to simulate not having gps/location or poor/slow gps location.
I'm trying to simulate and test what happens if my location request times out.
(Yes, I've tried the microwave, and I don't own a basement )

Comment: Try this, turn flight mode ON and then location will only allow GPS receiver to work. Which will make the phone unable to get a GPS fix in indoors (preferably in ground floor).

Answer (score 2):

There's no way to do that right now.  Star the feature request to encourage Google's engineers to add it:

[Android Public Tracker > App Development > Android Studio > Emulator > Allow simulating no location available.](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128345270)

Answer (score 1):

Try finding an area of a building with poor or no cell tower signal and turn off wifi to disable wifi based location service.
I've had good luck with going down into the basement of our building with wifi turned off to delay location positioning.

Just saw your edit about no basement.  On one of my older phones, I could open the cover and disconnect the antennae.  Don't know if you can still do that on modern phones.

Comment: I've got no basement, and my microwave doesn't seem to do the trick either. More importantly, it's 2017, I refuse to accept there's still no official way to simulate this 
Appreciate your answer though! I'll go basement hunting tomorrow if I don't find anything before then..

Comment: Maybe there's a potential market here?.. Basements as a Service (BaaS)

Comment: Or a nice Faraday cage to block all signals.